# Find $a$, $b$ in the degree-$5$ polynomial with a given factor

Tags: polynomials

If $x^2-5x+3$ is a factor of $2x^5-11x^4+ax^3+bx^2+29x-12$ , find $a,b$.

I tried long division but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: What was the **remainder** you got after doing the long division?

Comment: I couldn't complete the long division. If I would have , then it would have been easy to solve.

Comment: Show us how far you got with it

Comment: Do you know what a division algebra is? If not, why did you pick that tag?

Comment: "I couldn't complete the long division": try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply out
$$
(x^2-5x+3)(2x^3+r_1x^2+r_2x+r_3)
$$
to match the degree $5$ polynomial. This gives linear equations, namely
$r_1=-1$, $r_2=3$, $r_3=-4$, so that $a=14$ and $b=-22$.

Answer (score 1):

By long division,

$$2x^5 −11x^4 +ax^3 +bx^2 +29x−12=(2x^3-x^2+(a-11)x+(5a+b-52))(x^2-5x+3)\\
+(5b+22a-198)x-3b-15a+144.$$

The resolution of the system

$$\begin{cases}5b+22a-198=0,\\-3b-15a+144=0\end{cases}$$ gives $a=14,b=-22.$